# Difference between the MouseOver and PointerOver in VisualStateManager

Tags: wpf, xaml, visualstatemanager

I was wandering if someone could explain the difference between `MouseOver` and `PointerOver`? I am creating a custom `ComboBoxItem` Style, and using [`this`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709911.aspx) link as a startpoint. After creating a playing around I discovered that the VisualState `PointerOver` that they use doesn't work. I remebered using `MouseOver` in a different Style so I replaced PointerOver with MouseOver.

So I was wandering if there a sepcific reason why MSDN would use PointerOver instead of MouseOver, if there is a reason other than being able to call it one self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the state `PointerOver` and the `IsPointerOver` property appeared in `.NET 4.5`, and is actively used in Windows 8.

The main difference is that `MouseOver` works with mouse cursor, and `PointerOver` works as the mouse cursor and the user's fingers or other means. This is due to the fact that Windows 8 more mobile platform than the old versions, hence it is more focused on working with TouchPad. Therefore, Microsoft is more focused on the support of their latest operating system versions.

*`The conclusion is:`* if your application is more focused on Windows 8 and mobile applications, then you need to use PointOver. If your application will be used on versions below, then use MouseOver.

Comment: Yea after a bit of further investigation I noticed that about the Win 8 target, interesting about the touch thing however too tho. Thanks :)